# I am trying to download Steam to raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to download Steam to my raspberry Pi3 and it says "you are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run". How do I find the missing libraries?

Answer (score 5):

The Raspberry Pi 3 is an ARM7 architecture board.

Steam only supports x86 and amd64 (ie. Intel/AMD chips).

It's an entirely different processor architecture... the Steam binaries won't run on ARM.

So the short version is:  You can't, and unless Valve decides to port Steam (and all of the games) to the RPi, it will never happen.

Comment: Tho you basically right there are ways to run x86 and I believe amd64 as well. You can use qemu but I will not be fast. There is a more common one by Eltech (called Exagear when I remember correctly). Also Microsoft developed one as well. It is even possible to run Crysis on ARM. But I should mention that the Pi is not that fast if you try to use Games or something like Editing Softwares.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this does not directly answer your question, but using RetroPie(yeah, i'm one of those who have a rpi3 just for playing for now...) i use [`moonlight-embedded`](https://github.com/irtimmer/moonlight-embedded) to stream games from my PC to Raspberry Pi 3 through network like a remote desktop protocol. The prerequisites are:

- Windows computer with Steam installed
- Nvidia card with nvidia experience software
- At least a GTX650 Ti card